# Append TextView Using Google Cloud Messaging data

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I wanna try make some chat apps using GCM.
I try to learn step by step and confused on:

- How to append the `TextView` in my `ReceiveActivity`.
- How to append `TextView` in my `Activity` without tapping the notification from `BroadcastReceiver`?

This is my `GCMIntentService.java`, I want the data from this class shown in `ReceiveActivity` without tapping the notification

```
package com.fahri.runningchat;import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
Context context;


public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

     if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                sendNotification(msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());                   

            }
        }
     GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    //Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And this is my `ReceiveActivity`, I want the message from server directly appended to the `TextView` without tapping the notification.

```
public class ReceiveActivity extends Activity {


JSONObject json;
EditText isian;
public static TextView pesan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    isian = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    pesan= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViews);
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    Log.e("message",message);
    pesan.setText(message+"");



}
public void kirim(View view)
{

    String url = "http://deaven.bl.ee/nyoba.php";
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", isian.getText().toString()));
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```

Thank You

Comment: I Would make some sort of app internal messaging service, that notifies fragments/activities that there is some new data/setting/whatever that needs to be handled. This way you dont have to keep a reference to the activity in question in the broadcast receiver =D

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solved my problem. I try to search how to use localBroadcast and whenever GCM data receive, it will append to my textView without clicking my app notification.
I found this post is very helpfull for me [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)